# When does Browsers Garbage Collect?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, chromium

Do Browsers allocate memory for each tab? If that's true, how much memory is allocated for each tab. And when Browsers do GC? It's my doubts that are improving our Web App's performance. I need this one. So please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Google Chrome, every single tab that is opened work as a standalone process. So I supposed that the garbage collect works for every tab independetly.
However, in the developer page of Mozilla, there are some documentation related to Memory Management, and how other browsers work with it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: Thanks for your reply.